# Python pymongo try key if it exists

Tags: python, pymongo

I have db that take many key, but not all are need at begin

```
book.insert_one({
                "id": form.tagNumber.data,
                "machine": form.machineNumber.data,
                "data": form.date.data,
                "change": form.change.data,
                "service": mService,
                "cableType": form.cableType.data,
                "order": form.order.data,
                "entryNumber": form.entryNumber.data,
                "operation": mOperation,
                "izolacja": mIzol,
                "ekranWZ": mEkrWZ,
                "ekranW": mEkrW,
                "ekranZ": mEkrZ,
                "prevNumber": form.previousNumber.data,
                "takeOff": form.takeOff.data,
                "takeOn": form.takeUp.data,
                "length": form.length.data,
                "cutOff": form.cutOff.data,
                "nextOperation": form.nextOperation.data

        })
```

only key: "machine" and "id" have value

In Flask form i want to assign key value if it exists.

```
    bookPozition = book.find({"machine": numerMaszyny}).sort("id", -1).limit(1)[0]
    form.tagNumber.data = bookPozition["id"]
        form.machineNumber.data = bookPozition["machine"]
        form.date.data = bookPozition["data"]
        form.change.data = bookPozition["change"]
...
...
```

Is there a way to tray if key exists or do i have save:
{key: null }
to db to avoid error??

Comment: If you use `bookPozition.get` with the key it will return `None` if it doesn't exist. See the documentation for [**`dict.get`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: thank you it works great